# Chrome extension error: Require is not defined

Tags: javascript, require

My ambition is to include a folder, located in node_modules/. Using Node.js I can do:

```js
var example = require('example');
```

But in my Google Chrome extension it doesn't work, it throws the error:

> Require is not defined.

Comment: commonJS is not supported in the browser, only in node, please use ES modules instead. (use import not require)

Comment: @Rainb I tried but it seems complicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104433/how-to-import-es6-modules-in-content-script-for-chrome-extension/48121629#48121629

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy use skypack

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy you'll have to use asynchronous import function and not the import at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extensions support ES6 modules in content scripts. You can use the import statement to include modules:

```
import example from './path-to-node-modules/example';
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you want to use it in the background page or in the content script, but I assume you are talking about the background page.

In the manifest file :

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [ "scripts/require.js","scripts/main.js"]
}
```

In main.js:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "scripts"
});

require( [ /*...*/ ], function(  /*...*/ ) {
    /*...*/

});
```

then in background.html:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/require.js>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Quick & Simple Bundling With `esbuild`

If your project requirements permit, consider using a bundler like `esbuild` to help avoid compatibility issues by transpiling the syntax into browser-compatible code. The setup is quick and unlike other bundlers such as `webpack`, setup of a config file is not required.

### Step-by-Step

`esbuild` is a fast and modern bundler with quick set-up. Other bundlers like `parcel` could work too (see [detailed guide](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/chrome-extension-with-parcel-tailwind/)).

1. #### Installing the Bundler

   Run the following command to install `esbuild` as a dependency (see [documentation](https://esbuild.github.io/getting-started/#install-esbuild)):

   ```
   npm install --save-exact esbuild
   ```
2. #### Bundling the Scripts

   Once installed, you can execute the following command in your root directory (i.e., where `package.json` is located) to bundle your client-side code:

   ```
   esbuild src/content.js --bundle --outfile=dist/bundle.js
   ```

   Using `esbuild` to bundle `content.js` will handle all imported modules, including `my-script.js`, and include them in the output `bundle.js`.

   Please note that `src` should be replaced with the correct file path for `content.js`, which I assume is a single entry point. Depending on your project requirements, `esbuild` supports set up of multiple entry points too (see [documentation](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#entry-points)).

### Explanation

#### Checking Syntax

Using a bundler like `esbuild` will transpile the files as browser-compatible ES syntax by default, meaning it can handle scenarios where there are files with a mix of ES and CommonJS syntax or files with only CommonJS syntax (see [documentation](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#javascript)).

#### Browser Compatibility

Browsers can return errors if ES syntax is not a supported version or is not used consistently for imports and exports in scripts. To handle version incompatibility, we can target a specific version of the ES syntax by using the `--target` flag in `esbuild` (see [documentation](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#target)).

Answer (score -1):

The error message "Require is not defined" typically indicates that you are trying to use the CommonJS require function in a context where it is not available. In Chrome extensions, the require function is not supported in content scripts or background scripts by default.

Use ES6 Modules: Modern Chrome extensions primarily use ES6 modules. Instead of require, use import and export statements to manage your module dependencies.

```
import someModule from './module.js';
```

Answer (score -2):

I didn't find the way to directly run node modules in snippet of Chrome. However, you can run node debug instead.

1. npm install -g node-inspector(to install the node debug module)
2. node-debug app.js (to run the node debug)

Then, the chrome will open a debug window, which you can query yourself by using the url of http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858; 
And this debug is based on the v8 debug of Chrome itself.