# How to import ES6 modules in content script for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ecmascript-6

In **Chrome 61**, support for modules in JavaScript was added. Right now I am running Chrome 63.

I am trying to use `import`/`export` syntax in Chrome extension content script to use modules.

In **`manifest.json`**:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "js": [
            "content.js"
        ],
    }
]
```

In **`my-script.js`** (same directory as **`content.js`**):

```
'use strict';

const injectFunction = () => window.alert('hello world');

export default injectFunction;
```

In **`content.js`**:

```
'use strict';

import injectFunction from './my-script.js';
injectFunction();
```

I receive this error: **`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`**

If I change the import syntax to `import {injectFunction} from './my-script.js';` I get this error: **`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`**

Is there some issue with using this syntax in **`content.js`** in Chrome extension (since in HTML you have to use `<script type="module" src="script.js">` syntax), or am I doing something wrong? It seems strange that Google would ignore support for extensions.

Comment: Chrome has support for modules with an asterisk: Only works when your script is a module script. The `import` statement is synchronous which doesn't work well with normal JavaScript.

Comment: How do you make a script to be a module script?

Comment: You don't need to. Simply add the path to `my-script.js` to the list in your `manifest.json` and it will be loaded according to the order you specified.

Comment: Can you please provide an example as an answer so it can be potentially marked as a correct anwer please?

Comment: Content scripts are unusual scripts, which are injected through an absolutely different mechanism, not like page scripts, so there's no support for ES6 modules. You can list the scripts files in manifest so they all get injected and run in the same execution context i.e. sharing the global isolated world.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### Disclaimer

*First of all, it’s important to say that content scripts don’t support modules as of January 2018. This workaround sidesteps the limitation by embedding module `script` tag into the page that leads back to your extension.*

## THIS IS AN UNSAFE WORKAROUND!

**A web page script (or another extension) can exploit your code and extract/spoof the data** by using setters/getters on `Object.prototype` and other prototypes, proxying functions and/or global objects, because the code inside a `script` element runs in the JS context of the page, not in the safe isolated JS environment where content scripts run by default.

A safe workaround is the dynamic `import()` shown in [another answer here](/a/53033388).

## Workaround

This is my **`manifest.json`**:

```json
    "content_scripts": [ {
       "js": [
         "content.js"
       ]
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
       "main.js",
       "my-script.js"
    ]
```

Note that I have two scripts in `web_accessible_resources`.

This is my **`content.js`**:

```js
    'use strict';
    
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type", "module");
    script.setAttribute("src", chrome.extension.getURL('main.js'));
    const head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
    head.insertBefore(script, head.lastChild);
```

This will insert `main.js` into the webpage as a module script.

All my business logic is now in `main.js`.

For this method to work, `main.js` (as well as all scripts that I will  `import`) *must* be in `web_accessible_resources` in the manifest.

#### Example Usage:  **`my-script.js`**

```js
    'use strict';
    
    const injectFunction = () => window.alert('hello world');
    
    export {injectFunction};
```

And in **`main.js`** this is an example of importing the script:

```js
    'use strict';
    
    import {injectFunction} from './my-script.js';
    injectFunction();
```

This works! No errors are thrown, and I am happy. :)

Comment: Nice solution. The only problem is that the chrome.runtime APIs become unavailable :(

Comment: Can you be please more specific what your issue is?

Comment: For instance,  if in your main.js above, you had `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse), () => ...)` the handler will never be called. There's no workaround for that as that's by design. But I'm using Webpack to compile my extension into a single file, so it's not an issue for me.

Comment: Another drawback: "modules" are async. If you are trying to injects js that should execute before the target page's own js, that doesn't work anymore.
Of course, that may not matter depending on one's needs.

Comment: I don't recommend this pattern, since it removes the context isolation from your content scripts. In addition to that it allows websites to detect you extension. This is a security vulnerability.

Comment: ↑ no one's *recommending* it, it's a workaround until browser implementations catch-up.
@ ragnar: thanks for the nice clear example; for the record, this technique seems to work well for me in firefox 56 as well (with `dom.moduleScripts.enabled`)

Comment: To make this work in 2021, I had to replace `chrome.extension.getURL` with `chrome.runtime.getURL`, and `"web_accessible_resources": ["main.js", "my-script.js"]` to `"web_accessible_resources": {"resources": ["main.js", "my-script.js"], "matches": ["*://*/*"]}`

Comment: What is the state of it in 2022? I believe this workaround is still recommended

Answer (score 105):

#### Asynchronous [dynamic `import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) function for ES modules

Unlike the unsafe workaround using a `<script>` element, this one runs in the same safe JS environment (assuming you use the default world i.e. not `MAIN`), where your imported module can still access the global variables and functions of the initial content script, including the built-in `chrome` API like `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.

In `content_script.js`, it looks like

```js
(async () => {
  const src = chrome.runtime.getURL("your/content_main.js");
  const contentMain = await import(src);
  contentMain.main();
})();
```

You'll also need to declare the imported scripts in manifest's [Web Accessible Resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources):

// ManifestV3

```json
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
     "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
     "resources": ["your/content_main.js"]
   }],
```

// ManifestV2

```json
  "web_accessible_resources": [
     "your/content_main.js"
  ]
```

For more details:

- [How to use ES6 “import” with Chrome Extension](https://medium.com/@otiai10/how-to-use-es6-import-with-chrome-extension-bd5217b9c978)
- [Working Example of ES6 import in Chrome Extension](https://github.com/otiai10/chrome-extension-es6-import)
- [`chrome.runtime.getURL`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL)

#### Synchronous "import" workaround for normal non-module scripts

Use a normal non-module script, add its name to `"js"` in "content_scripts" before your main content script, then simpy use the global variables/functions directly ([example](/a/58137279/)).

Comment: Nice solution. It might be worth mentioning that scripts imported using this technique need to be allowlisted as `web_accessible_resources` in manifest. Not allowlisting them will result in `GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED` error. This may not be obvious because regular content scripts don't need to be allowlisted.

Comment: This worked for me a few weeks ago, and now is throwing `Request scheme 'chrome-extension' is unsupported
    at sw.js:42` in Chrome >= 71. I see by stepping through the code that sw.js is using fetch to load my js files from an extension sandbox. Trying to make sure I haven't changed something else, but if someone else sees the same behavior please confirm.

Comment: This works in Chrome but not in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1536094

Comment: The bug linked above has been resolved, and this strategy should work in Firefox 89. It already works in the latest Nightly!

Comment: Any quick way to make the import function work synchronously? Otherwise you can't just wrap this in a function and rely on having the library imported.

Comment: Important to note that you only need to dynamically import the initial script, nested imports can be done in `esm` format

Comment: If you're using webpack, add `/*webpackIgnore: true*/` inside of your `import` call to get webpack to leave the import alone (this method didn't work without it for me).

Comment: @fisch2 saved my day! lol. `import(/*webpackIgnore: true*/ 'path_to_your.js');`

Comment: I don't understand why the dynamic import still doesn't work for me. When transpiled, Chrome complains about the `require` keyword in .js file

Comment: @otiaai10 How we can import another js into content_main.js ?

Comment: I found `import("your/content_main.js");` works the same, which is easier to remember. Also, it seems important to note that all other files can use `import { x } from "./y.js"` style imports. I assumed I would have to use`import()` in all files, but that is not the case, only the first file requires it.

Comment: `webextension-polyfill` solutions?

Comment: If you are in MAIN world and you don't have access to `chrome.runtime.getURL()`, know that you don't have to use `chrome.runtime.getURL("your/content_main.js")`, you can directly use `await import("./your/content_main.js")` or the appropriate relative path.

Answer (score 30):

Static `import` statement is not available in content scripts.

#### A workaround using global scope

Content scripts live in their own ['isolated world'](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#isolated_world) sharing the same isolated global namespace that is only accessible to content scripts of your extension (either declared in manifest.json or injected programmatically) and not to the page scripts.

> Warning: if your content script was declared/injected in the **`MAIN` world** in a ManifestV3 extension, this approach can't be used as your globals will be exposed to the page. Instead, combine all dependent scripts in one bundle with an IIFE.

Here's the implementation:

**manifest.json**

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": [
      "content-scripts/globals.js",
      "content-scripts/script1.js",
      "content-scripts/script2.js"
    ]
  }
],
```

**globals.js**

```
globalThis.foo = 123;
```

**script1.js**

```
some_fn_that_needs_foo(globalThis.foo);
```

Same way you can factor out re-usable functions and other actors you would otherwise `import` in content script files.

N.B.: global namespace of content scripts is not available to any pages besides content scripts - so there is little to no global scope pollution.

In case you need to import some libs - you will have to use a bundler like `Parcel` to package up your content script files along with the needed libs into one `huge-content-script.js` and then metion it in `manifest.json`.

P.S.: [docs on globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)

Comment: Excellent. It's not an easy mindset to be in if you are not used to.

Comment: This is not working for me, I receive an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`

Comment: @fguillen, remove the `export` keyword from your file

Comment: Important! The order of scripts in the manifest.json is critical. If you rely on a script that is below the one you're making the call from, it won't be available.

Comment: answer + comments here - absolute life saver!

Comment: Is there a way to work around `no-undef` and `no-unused-vars` eslint errors using this approach?

Answer (score 25):

The best way would be to use bundlers like webpack or Rollup.

I got away with basic configuration

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    background: './background.js',
    content: './content.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build')
  }
};
```

Run the file with the command

```
webpack --config ./ext/webpack-ext.config.js
```

Bundlers combine the related files and we can use modularisation in chrome extensions! :D

You will need to keep all other files like manifest and static files in build folder.

Play around with it and you will eventually find a way to make it work!

Comment: How is this not upvoted more? much better than dynamic imports and other hacks :)

Comment: Any chance you've tried this with Vite? It uses Rollup but my bundled files still have an `import` in them.

Comment: Using Rollup instead → https://www.extend-chrome.dev/rollup-plugin#usage

Answer (score 10):

I just stumbled across this question while trying to solve the same thing myself.

Anyways, I think there's a simpler solution to injecting your own custom modules into your **content script**. I was looking at how Jquery is injected and it occurs to me you can do the same thing by creating an **IIFE** (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), and declaring it in your **manifest.json**

It goes something like this:

In your manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["https://*"],
  "css": ["css/popup.css"],
  "js": ["helpers/helpers.js"]
}],
```

Then just create an IIFE in your helpers/helpers.js:

```
var Helpers = (function() {
  var getRandomArbitrary = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }
  return {
    getRandomArbitrary: getRandomArbitrary
  }
})()
```

Now, you can freely use your helper functions in your content script:

```
Helpers.getRandomArbitrary(0, 10) // voila!
```

I think it's great if you use this method to refactor some of your generic functions. Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice idea! Just say if I'm wrong, but those content scripts are included immediatly each time the user loads a page?

Comment: @Boiethios if you put  "run_at": "document_start" they run at the beginning of the page load, if you put "document_end"... they run at the end

Answer (score 5):

### For Vite Users: CRXJS

There is this awesome plugin called [crxjs](https://crxjs.dev/vite-plugin/getting-started/react/content-script-hmr), you just need to update it in `vite.config.ts` and give the path to your `manifest.json` (it works only with `manifets_version >= 3`).

Follow the below steps to get your script running:

1. Add crxjs to your project:

   ```bash
   npm install --save-dev @crxjs/vite-plugin
   ```
2. Create or update `manifest.json`:

   ```json
   {
     "manifest_version": 3,
     "name": "CRXJS React Vite Example",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "action": { "default_popup": "index.html" }
   }
   ```
3. Update your `vite.config.ts` file with path to the manifest:

   ```js
   import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
   import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
   import { crx } from '@crxjs/vite-plugin'
   import manifest from './manifest.json'

   export default defineConfig({
     plugins: [
       react(),
       crx({ manifest }),
     ],
   })
   ```

After this setup, run your project. Now `config.js` will be bundled, and you can import packages in it.

Comment: Omg, I was configuring Vite myself until I ran into this problem. Thanks, this is the best tool ever!

Answer (score 2):

### Using Rollup bundler

full tutorial: https://www.extend-chrome.dev/rollup-plugin#usage

---

### TL;DR

```sh
npm i -D rollup\
   rollup-plugin-chrome-extension@latest\
   @rollup/plugin-node-resolve\
   @rollup/plugin-commonjs
```

`rollup.config.js`:

```js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'

import { chromeExtension, simpleReloader } from 'rollup-plugin-chrome-extension'

export default {
  input: 'src/manifest.json',
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'esm',
  },
  plugins: [
    // always put chromeExtension() before other plugins
    chromeExtension(),
    simpleReloader(),
    // the plugins below are optional
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
  ],
}
```

`package.json`:

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "start": "rollup -c -w"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using esbuild

Further to [Dhruvil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56783515/1442622), here's a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mattburrell/simple-chrome-extension-esbuild) showing how to use esbuild to bundle content scripts written in TypeScript and React - therefore enabling you to import es6 modules.

It also includes bundling the background service worker and popup, with scripts that enable Hot Module Reloading when running the popup locally.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**

You can mimic some of the functionality and get some of the benefits of `import`/`export` in browser extensions by creating the following file and listing it early in your `manifest.json`:

```
let exportVars, importVarsFrom;
{
  const modules = {};
  exportVars = varsObj => ({
    from(nameSpace) {
      modules[nameSpace] || (modules[nameSpace] = {});
      for (let [k,v] of Object.entries(varsObj)) {
        modules[nameSpace][k] = v;
      }
    }
  });
  importVarsFrom = nameSpace => modules[nameSpace];
}
```

Then, export from one file/module like this:

```
exportVars({ var1, var2, var3 }).from('my-utility');
```

Import into another file/module like this:

```
const { var1, var3: newNameForVar3 } = importVarsFrom('my-utility');
```

**Discussion:**

This strategy:

- allows **modular code** in a browser extension such that you can split code into multiple files but don't have variable clashes due to shared global scope between different files,
- still allows you to **export and import variables** out of and into different JavaScript files/modules,
- introduces **only two global variables**, namely the exporting function and the importing function,
- maintains **full browser extension functionality** in each file (e.g. `chrome.runtime`, etc.) that is eliminated by, e.g., the approach in another answer (currently the accepted answer) using module script tag embedding,
- uses a **concise syntax similar to the true `import` and `export`** functions in JavaScript,
- allows **name-spacing** which could be the file names of the exporting modules in a manner similar to how the true `import` and `export` commands work in JavaScript, but doesn't have to be (i.e. the name-space names could be anything you want), and
- allows **variable renaming** upon import similar to how `import { fn as myFn }...` works.

To do this, your `manifest.json` needs to load your JavaScript as follows:

- the file establishing the exporting/importing functions first (named `modules-start.js` in the example below),
- the exporting files next, and
- the importing files last.

Of course, you might have a file that both imports and exports. In that case, just ensure it is listed after the files it imports from but before the files it exports to.

**Working Example**

The following code demonstrates this strategy.

It is important to note that all of the code in each module/file is contained within curly braces. The only exception is the first line in `modules-start.js` which establishes the exporting and importing functions as global variables.

The code in the snippet below is necessarily contained in a single "place". In a real project, however, the code could be split into separate files. Note, though, that even in this artificial context here (i.e. within the single code snippet below), this strategy allows the different sections of code it contains to be modular and yet still interconnected.

```js
// modules-start.js:
let exportVars, importVarsFrom; // the only line NOT within curly braces
{
  const modules = {};
  exportVars = varsObj => ({
    from(nameSpace) {
      modules[nameSpace] || (modules[nameSpace] = {});
      for (let [k,v] of Object.entries(varsObj)) {
        modules[nameSpace][k] = v;
      }
    }
  });
  importVarsFrom = nameSpace => modules[nameSpace];
}


// *** All of the following is just demo code
// *** showing how to use this export/import functionality:

// my-general-utilities.js (an example file that exports):
{
  const wontPolluteTheGlobalScope = 'f';
  const myString = wontPolluteTheGlobalScope + 'oo';
  const myFunction = (a, b) => a + b;
  
  // the export statement:
  exportVars({ myString, myFunction }).from('my-general-utilities');
}

// content.js (an example file that imports):
{
  // the import statement:
  const { myString, myFunction: sum } = importVarsFrom('my-general-utilities');

  console.log(`The imported string is "${myString}".`);
  console.log(`The renamed imported function shows that 2 + 3 = ${sum(2,3)}.`);
}
```

With this example, your `manifest.json` should list the files in the following order:

```
{ ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "modules-start.js",
        "my-general-utilities.js",
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ], ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Quick Setup: use chrome-extension-cli

`chrome-extension-cli` package  solves this problem by installing and preconfiguring webpack. This allows you to import packages or modules easily

> #### Get Started Immediately
>
> You **don’t** need to install or configure Webpack.
> Webpack comes in preconfigured, so that you can focus on the code.
>
> Just create a project, and you’re good to go.

Read More: https://github.com/dutiyesh/chrome-extension-cli

Answer (score 0):

## Quick & Simple Bundling With `esbuild`

If your project requirements permit, consider using a bundler like `esbuild` to help avoid compatibility issues by transpiling the syntax into browser-compatible code. The setup is quick and unlike other bundlers such as `webpack`, setup of a config file is not required.

### Step-by-Step

`esbuild` is a fast and modern bundler with quick set-up. Other bundlers like `parcel` could work too (see [detailed guide](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/chrome-extension-with-parcel-tailwind/)).

1. #### Installing the Bundler

   Run the following command to install `esbuild` as a dependency (see [documentation](https://esbuild.github.io/getting-started/#install-esbuild)):

   ```
   npm install --save-exact esbuild
   ```
2. #### Bundling the Scripts

   Once installed, you can execute the following command in your root directory (i.e., where `package.json` is located) to bundle your client-side code:

   ```
   esbuild src/content.js --bundle --outfile=dist/bundle.js
   ```

   Using `esbuild` to bundle `content.js` will handle all imported modules, including `my-script.js`, and include them in the output `bundle.js`.

   Please note that `src` should be replaced with the correct file path for `content.js`, which I assume is a single entry point. Depending on your project requirements, `esbuild` supports set up of multiple entry points too (see [documentation](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#entry-points)).
3. #### Copying `manifest.json`

   The `dist` folder should also contain a copy of the `manifest.json` file, revised with the updated path to the bundled file.

   **Before:**

   ```
   "content_scripts": [
       {
           "js": [
               "content.js"
           ],
       }
   ]
   ```

   **After:**

   ```
   "content_scripts": [
       {
           "js": [
               "bundle.js"
           ],
       }
   ]
   ```

### Explanation

#### Checking Syntax

Using a bundler like `esbuild` will transpile the files as browser-compatible ES syntax by default, meaning it can handle scenarios where there are files with a mix of ES and CommonJS syntax or files with only CommonJS syntax (see [documentation](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#javascript)).

#### Browser Compatibility

Browsers can return errors if ES syntax is not a supported version or is not used consistently for imports and exports in scripts. To handle version incompatibility, we can target a specific version of the ES syntax by using the `--target` flag in `esbuild` (see [documentation](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#target)).

Answer (score -1):

**Add simply in manifest.json in V2**

**Note! After changing in manifest.json, make sure to reload the extension and browser tab**

```
{ ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "modules-start.js",
        "my-general-utilities.js",
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ], ...
}
```

Answer (score -11):

Export the module as a object:

```
'use strict';

const injectFunction = () => window.alert('hello world');

export {injectFunction};
```

Then you can import its property:

```
'use strict';
import {injectFunction} from './my-script.js';
```

Comment: It still leads to Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: How about  add 'use strict';  ?

Comment: Try removing "default" keyword~