# Importing package into Content Script

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, graphql

I have a Chrome extension made initially with create-react-app. This extension needs to get data via a GraphQL query, and the resulting data needs to be used in my content script.

Using the 'react-boost' package in my `src/index.js` file works perfectly as follows.

```
import ApolloClient, { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'https://mygraphqlurl/graphql',
  headers: {
    'access-key': '123',
  },
});

client
  .query({
    query: gql`
      {
        merchant {
          id
          retailer {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  })
  .then(result => console.log(result));
```

However, if I try to use this code in my `content.js` script in my `public` folder, I get an error on the import line:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier '
>
> `import ApolloClient, { gql } from 'apollo-boost';`

How can I use this functionality in my content script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import ES6 modules in content script for Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104433/how-to-import-es6-modules-in-content-script-for-chrome-extension)

Comment: I'm trying to load a javascript package installed via npm, not a local .js file though.

Comment: You'll need to build that package into a browser-compatible bundle before you can use it in a browser. Then proceed to the linked topic.