# Import a library into a chrome extension content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, import, libraries, require

I am looking to import a library into one of my chrome extension's content scripts. Lets take [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) for instance.
I've already looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104433/how-to-import-es6-modules-in-content-script-for-chrome-extension), but I'm not sure if it is what I need. If it is, then I must be doing something wrong, as I can't seem to get it to work.

I've looked everywhere but I can't seem to find anything regarding the use of libraries in chrome extensions.

Put simply, how can I use and import a javascript library into my chrome extension's content script, so that it can be used in the loaded page?

Thanks, KDJ

What I'm trying now:

chart.js is this file:
[image]

manifest.json:

[image]

In my injected script:
[image]

Error:
[image]

chrome.tabs.executeScript() is what spawns the script in which I'm trying to access the library.

Comment: Simply use the [bundle from CDN](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/chart.js?path=dist) and add it to your `content_scripts` declaration just like any other script. It will add a global variable e.g. `Chart` or whatever.

Comment: I have tried adding chart.js to content_scripts in the manifest, and then calling "var myChart = new Chart()" from my injected script.

However, it is not working, and I just get the reference error "Chart is not defined" when I test it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't see what you do though so I can only guess you load chart.js in the wrong order (it should be the first) or you use the wrong js file from CDN.

Comment: I updated the OP with some pictures. Do you see what the problem could be?

Comment: I guess you didn't reload the extension or you didn't reload the tab. BTW if you only use chart.js on demand then you don't need to list it in manifest.json - you can load it using executeScript before your main script.

Comment: I just got it working! I just had to make a few tweaks. Thank you so much for all of your help! I can't believe the solution was so simple.

Comment: @KDJ Can you explain how you fixed it? Having a similar issue with a different library.

Comment: @NNNComplex This was a long time ago, and I should have left a more detailed solution, but I believe what I did was simply remove the extension from chrome://extensions/ and then add it back again. For some reason either the manifest.json file wasn't being updated or the Chart.js file in the extension files wasn't being added with a normal refresh.