# How to properly inject React into content.js Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I ran into such a problem that I can not implement the react in the content.js file.
For those who do not know when creating an extension for chrome there is a pop-up window, this is a window in the corner on the right, content.js is a file that allows you to interact with the DOM.
**What should be done to inject React into this file**?

Error after inject React into content.js:

[image]

`Content.js`:

[image]

Comment: Isn't that some nodeJS code? don't you have to write some client javascript? I don't know that tech, but it looks like your trying to run nodejs code into plain javascript... ?

Comment: Sounds like your webpack config should be tweaked to generate a single bundle so there'll be no need for imports in the output code. Alternatively, there's an ugly workaround which I don't recommend: [How to import ES6 modules in content script for Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48104433)

Comment: @MathieuAuclair, it's a React Syntax.
I trying create some div, and append it in page.
And then - render all components inside
Default react

Comment: Cool I didn't know, good to know :)