# How can I inject a module script into a client's browser tab via a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, es6-modules

I am trying to inject a module structured like "injection.js" below into a browser tab with a chrome extension structured like "extension.js". I am using manifest v3.

```
//injection.js
export function f(){...}
export function g(){...}
export default function main(){
  f()
  g()
}
```

```
//extension.js
import main from "./injection.js";

...
chrome.scripting.executeScript({target: {tabId: tabs[0].id}, function:main });//tabs[0].id is defined elsewhere
...
```

However, I receive an error, because `f` and `g` are undefined, since it literally seems to only be injecting `main`. If I try to inject the entire file `injection.js`, I receive an error for using the keyword `export` since I can't specify I am injecting a module.

I am aware that I could wrap all 3 functions in injection.js with a wrapper function to resolve this problem. However, this makes running tests on functions `f` and `g` difficult, since I have no way of isolating them for unit tests.

Is there a way to inject modules into tabs on chrome extensions?

(This is a simplified version of my actual code. For example, my actual code has the return values of `f` and `g` interacting with each other. But for the purpose of highlighting the problem, I included only necessary info)

Comment: The injected code runs in a different page in a different OS process so you can't do what you want.

Comment: What is the best practice then for injecting the functions then, while still keeping them testable?

Comment: I guess you're using webpack or another bundler so you can add an entry that produces a separate file for injection.js which you will specify in `files` parameter instead of `function`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/53033388/9080566