# How to use imports in content script with Vite without external library like https://crxjs.dev/vite-plugin?

Tags: vite, browser-extension

There's an issue with importing es modules into the content script:
([How to import ES6 modules in content script for Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104433/how-to-import-es6-modules-in-content-script-for-chrome-extension))

Maybe there is a way to build the content script in one file to resolve this?

I'm using this boilerplate - https://github.com/JohnBra/vite-web-extension. Here's what my vite config looks like:

```
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import { resolve } from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import copyContentStyle from "./utils/plugins/copy-content-style";
import makeManifest from "./utils/plugins/make-manifest";

const root = resolve(__dirname, "src");
const pagesDir = resolve(root, "pages");
const assetsDir = resolve(root, "assets");
const outDir = resolve(__dirname, "dist");
const publicDir = resolve(__dirname, "public");

const IS_DEV = process.env.DEV === "true";

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@src": root,
      "@assets": assetsDir,
      "@pages": pagesDir,
    },
  },
  plugins: [react(), makeManifest(), copyContentStyle()],
  publicDir,
  build: {
    minify: !IS_DEV,
    outDir,
    sourcemap: IS_DEV,
    emptyOutDir: IS_DEV,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        // devtools: resolve(pagesDir, 'devtools', 'index.html'),
        // panel: resolve(pagesDir, "panel", "index.html"),
        content: resolve(pagesDir, "content", "index.ts"),
        background: resolve(pagesDir, "background", "index.ts"),
        popup: resolve(pagesDir, "popup", "index.html"),
        // newtab: resolve(pagesDir, "newtab", "index.html"),
        // options: resolve(pagesDir, "options", "index.html"),
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: (chunk) => {
          return `src/pages/${chunk.name}/index.js`;
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I tried having a separate vite config for the content scripts to build it in one file. But, I was not successful

Here's what the config for that looks like:

```
import { resolve } from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import copyContentStyle from "./utils/plugins/copy-content-style";
import { viteSingleFile } from "vite-plugin-singlefile";

const root = resolve(__dirname, "src");
const pagesDir = resolve(root, "pages");
const assetsDir = resolve(root, "assets");
const outDir = resolve(__dirname, "dist");
const publicDir = resolve(__dirname, "public");

const IS_DEV = process.env.DEV === "true";

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@src": root,
      "@assets": assetsDir,
      "@pages": pagesDir,
    },
  },
  plugins: [copyContentStyle(), viteSingleFile()],
  publicDir,
  build: {
    minify: !IS_DEV,
    outDir,
    sourcemap: IS_DEV,
    emptyOutDir: IS_DEV,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        content: resolve(pagesDir, "content", "index.ts"),
      },
      output: {
        dir: `src/pages/content`,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up having a separate vite config for the content script, which looks like:

```
import { resolve } from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { viteSingleFile } from "vite-plugin-singlefile";

const root = resolve(__dirname, "src");
const pagesDir = resolve(root, "pages");
const outDir = resolve(__dirname, "dist", "src", "pages", "content");

const IS_DEV = process.env.DEV === "true";

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@src": root,
      "@pages": pagesDir,
    },
  },
  plugins: [viteSingleFile()],
  build: {
    copyPublicDir: false,
    minify: !IS_DEV,
    outDir,
    sourcemap: IS_DEV,
    emptyOutDir: IS_DEV,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        content: resolve(pagesDir, "content", "index.ts"),
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: "index.js",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

And, I run it all with:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build:general": "vite build",
    "build:content": "vite build --config vite.contentScript-config.ts",
    "build": "run-p build:*",
    "dev:general": "vite build --watch --mode development",
    "dev:content": "vite build --config vite.contentScript-config.ts --watch --mode development",
    "dev": "run-p dev:*"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already building with react and Vite, check out [CRXjs](https://crxjs.dev/vite-plugin/getting-started/react/create-project). Handy utility for building extensions.

The plugin will take care of how `content` and `service worker` files are made available to the extension (see docs as well). Huge plus is HMR while you're developing.

Should make it easy to write you manifest in ts/js (esm) and pass that to the vite config like so:

```js
// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { crx } from '@crxjs/vite-plugin'
import manifest from './manifest.json' // or manifest.ts / manifest.js

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    crx({ 
      manifest // <--- pass in your manifest here
    }),
  ],
})
```

assuming a valid (MV3) manifest like:

```js
const manifest = {
 name: 'extension-name'
 version: '0.0.1',
 manifest_version: 3,
 // ...other manifest fields
}
```