# Chrome Extension: Content script error "Cannot use import statement outside a module" - React.js / Vite

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, content-script

React.js + Vite

I am trying to build a widget and I have this error:

> Cannot use import statement outside a module

ContentScript.tsx

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const Hello = () => {
    return <div>HELLO EXTENSION!</div>;
};

const AppContainer = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(AppContainer);
const root = createRoot(AppContainer);
root.render(<Hello />);
```

Unfortunately none of the solutions in this thread worked.

[How to import ES6 modules in content script for Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104433/how-to-import-es6-modules-in-content-script-for-chrome-extension)

Answer (score -2):

You will need to go to your package.json file and add

```
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

This will make your project treat the files as ES modules, allowing you to use "import"

Comment: It doesn't work.