# ES6 Import Error in Chrome Extension Content Script using React

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, vite

I'm facing an issue with my Chrome extension that I'm developing using React and Vite.

Problem:
When I try to run my extension, I encounter the following error:

""”Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"""

This error is triggered by the ES6 import statements in my content script:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.tsx";

const extensionDiv = document.createElement("div");
extensionDiv.id = "my-chrome-extension-root";
document.body.appendChild(extensionDiv);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, extensionDiv);
```

What I've tried:

I've ensured that my manifest.json is correctly set up.
I've attempted to bundle the content script using Vite, but I'm unsure if I'm doing it correctly.
I've also considered declaring the script as a module in manifest.json, but I'm not sure if that's the right approach.

Question:
How can I correctly use ES6 imports in my content script and successfully inject my React app into webpages using Vite?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

---

Edited on Oct. 8:

Based on this ([How to import ES6 modules in content script for Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104433/how-to-import-es6-modules-in-content-script-for-chrome-extension?noredirect=1&lq=1)) article, I changed the code like this.

```
const extensionDiv = document.createElement("div");
extensionDiv.id = "mind-drive-root";
document.body.appendChild(extensionDiv);

import("./App.tsx").then(AppModule => {
    import("react-dom/client").then(ReactDOMModule => {
        const App = AppModule.default;
        const ReactDOM = ReactDOMModule.default;
        ReactDOM.render(<App />, extensionDiv);
    });
});
```

However, it still has an error like "Cannot use import ..."

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104433/how-to-import-es6-modules-in-content-script-for-chrome-extension

Comment: The final file can't use imports, so you must configure your bundler to produce a single file without any runtime chunks or imports.

Comment: Thank you so much, you guys. I tried based on the article, but it doesn't work like I wrote above. Also, I changed the setting of Vite to export only one file. However, it somehow exports multiple js files with the same name just like "chunk.js," "chunk1.js," "chunk2.js"...

Comment: Finally, I decided to try another method, just using the Chrome sidebar instead of the DOM injection, and successfully it worked. However, if anybody finds good solutions, lemme know :)