# What can do to compile my Chrome Extension js files?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm developing a Chrome extension, and the problem I'm facing is that it needs a `content.js` file and I can't import from other files.

This means that I have to write the entire extension code in one file, which makes it very hard to read and maintain.

What can I do? How can I break my files into different files in development  and compile them all into one single file for production?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104433/how-to-import-es6-modules-in-content-script-for-chrome-extension