Why am I getting this "Cannot use import statement outside a module" error in my browser extension?
I'm creating a very simple browser extension.  My code is below
manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "RedditReader",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [ "tabs", "activeTab", "scripting" ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "scripts":  "content.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "https://sizzler.com/" ],
            "js": [ "content.js", "messages.js" ]
        }
    ]
}

background.js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if(changeInfo.url) {
        console.log('URL UPDATED');
        if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.url.startsWith('https://sizzler.com/')) {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: tabId },
                files: ['content.js']
            });
        }
    }
});

content.js
import { ShowConfirmation } from './common.js';
import { successMessage } from './messages.js';

const GetSuccessMessage = () => {
    return successMessage;
};

if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
    const mySuccessMessage = GetSuccessMessage();
    if (ShowConfirmation()) {
       console.log(mySuccessMessage);
    }
}

messages.js
export const successMessage = 'Success!';

I keep getting this error:

I'm confused what I'm doing wrong.  I've attempted to add a package.json file, but that didn't seem to fix it.  I'm not the strongest with JavaScript so would appreciate any input!

Related, but possibly out of date: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53033388/47773

is "type": "module" for a content script documented somewhere?

@MatthewFlaschen yeah, technically that works, but I was hoping to get the import {} from '' syntax working.  While the linked solution works easily enough for my local files, it becomes inconvenient when I'm trying to import from external sources, like jquery

@JaromandaX you're right, that part is incorrect.  Copilot helped conjure that up so I missed it.  I'll edit to remove that now, but I'm still having the same issue

I haven't dealt with browser extensions in a while. I was thinking having a "stub" for content.js that simply uses the dynamic import syntax to load your content javascript, and as that is being imported as a module, you should now be able to use the import ... from syntax

... I just realised, that's exactly what the code in the link in the first comment is doing. Not sure why you think you can't use import {} from '' syntax using the linked (not accepted) answer?!
